# AEM jar not starting

Tags: java, osgi, aem, sling

I have an AEM jar file AEM_6.5_Quickstart. I am trying to get it running but facing issues.
First thing is my jar is not identified as normal on my system like other jars, as you can see there is no icon associated with my jar file.
[image]

Second is when i double click on it to run it i get the below prompt to choose the program to run it with, which ideally should not appear. I was getting errors when i was running maven command to generate project using zulu jdk so i had installed jdk from oracle website, now that is removed from my system and when i double click on jar file i still get the option to run it using oracle jdk

[image]

Third problem which i am facing is that when i run the jar using zulu x64 Architecture as in above image it starts the jar but i get the below error when i go to localhost:4502

[image]

i google searched for solutions and found that indexing might be the problem so i deleted the file at crx-quickstart/repository/index after stopping the jar. When i restart it it gets stuck and doesnt start for some reason as in below picture, the progress bar doesnt move even though i waited for hours. I also made sure that sling authenticator service was running.

[image]

This is the output in case it helps for the java version being used and the path is setup as C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-11\bin. I am unable to fix this issue, any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, delete the whole crx-quickstart directory (since this is a local environment being set up for the first time), and this way you will have a clean start. After that, maybe the .jar extension is missing from the filename, please add it. Finally, it is easier to use a .bat or .sh script (you can customize parameters and runmodes for AEM). But for a first run, quick setup with the default sample content, just try `java -jar AEM_6.5_Quickstart.jar`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like windows messed up with your java versions, you can go and fix your windows JDK references from the registry, you can do that by pressing win + R then type "regedit", once open look for the next value:
`"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\open\command"` then open the "default" value and check that your path is correct, mine for example is :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

use mine as reference only change the first part between quotes for your path to the JDK.

Usually that should fix it, but some times there are some other registry references that ruin your jar files association, if you can open PowerShell/cmd or bash terminal type java -version and get the proper version of your Java installation, another workaround can be opening terminal, navigate in terminal where your jar lives and then type

```
java -jar yourJarFile.jar
```